# No subtitle stream

Tags: chromecast, webvtt, vtt

#### Hi guys!

I try to get the subtitle working in chromecast app.
I'm using HLS streams and my m3u file has a subtitle specified but when I check streamCount on protocol I only recieve **one** stream which is a "video/mp2t" stream.

Maybe this isn't supported but I read in the release notes that subtitle now was actually supported?

The video plays as it should so all the playback is working, can't just enable the subtitle!

All help is welcome :)

## M3U file for playback

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-MEDIA:TYPE=SUBTITLES,GROUP-ID="subs", NAME="Norsk", DEFAULT=YES, FORCED=NO, URI="-- m3u8 url --",LANGUAGE="nb"
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:SUBTITLES="subs", PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=210000, RESOLUTION=320x180, CODECS="avc1.66.30, mp4a.40.2"
-- m3u8 url --
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:SUBTITLES="subs",PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=383000,RESOLUTION=480x270,CODECS="avc1.66.30, mp4a.40.2"
-- m3u8 url --
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:SUBTITLES="subs",PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=658000,RESOLUTION=640x360,CODECS="avc1.77.30, mp4a.40.2"
-- m3u8 url --
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:SUBTITLES="subs",PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=1387000,RESOLUTION=960x540,CODECS="avc1.77.30, mp4a.40.2"
-- m3u8 url --
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:SUBTITLES="subs",PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=2394000,RESOLUTION=1280x720
-- m3u8 url --
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:SUBTITLES="subs",PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=64000,CODECS="mp4a.40.2"
-- m3u8 url --
```

## M3U file for subtitle

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:30
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:0
#EXT-X-PLAYLIST-TYPE:VOD
#EXTINF:30.00000,   
KOIF43000411AA0.webvtt
#EXTINF:30.00000,   
KOIF43000411AA1.webvtt
#EXTINF:30.00000,   
.... and so on
```